# JavaScript - Saving/Loading an array with Local Storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I know that there is other questions on how to save arrays. Yet, I still don't know how to apply it to my situation...

So, I want to save and load this double-array's 2nd index:

```
var costume = [ //[name,price,owned]
    ["Mushroom",0,true],
    ["Agaric",20,false],
    ["Pumpkin",75,false],
    ["Shadow",100,false],
    ["Waffle",150,false]
];
```

The 2nd index in the array (which is set to 'true' or 'false') is changed to 'true' when the player buys a mushroom everything but loading works fine.

This is my code but it doesn't change 'costume' (the array above) to the one that i've saved.

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            localStorage["costumes"] = JSON.stringify(costume);

            var owned = JSON.parse(localStorage["costumes"]);

            for(var i = 0; i < costume.length; i++) {
                costume = owned;
            }
        }
```

Please help, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop looks meaningless.

If you want to load data from localStorage , call `localStorage["costumes"]` or 
`localStorage.getItem("costumes")`.

If you want to save data to localStorage , call `localStorage["costumes"] = JSON.stringify(costume)` or `localStorage.setItem('costumes', JSON.stringify(costume))`.

Don't try to update a reference to localStorage["costumes"].